# Did Harold Camping profit from his false prediction that the world would end?

Tags: religion

We all joke about it but there's probably lots of people that took him seriously.

Now that the world hasn't ended, many are claiming he is a fraud and a con man. Did Harold Camping or his Family Radio statement benefit financially from making this claim?

If so, how? Through donations? Publicity?

Comment: The news report of at least some people that gave *all* their belongings to Harold Camping. Let's see what we can dig up.

Comment: I've removed the "any other way" from the question: he obviously profited by having media coverage (hence notoriety).

Comment: @Sklivvz - now we know how to popularize Stack Exchange sites!

Comment: local newpaper claimed Harold invested 140.000$ of his savings in this worlds end. it seemed even probable he beleived in the end himself.

Comment: Does attention count as profit?

Comment: Regardless of whether he profited or not, Camping should pay(or at least split the cost with) Robert Fitzpatrick the 140k he spent putting ads in New York announcing the end of the world. http://www.91pan.com/post/new-york-man-spends-life-savings-ahead-of-may-21-doomsday-i-am-concerned-are-you/ I don't know which one made the dumbest move....

Comment: sick of him... how can people believe in a liar who lies and get caught twice already...

Comment: "Doomsday date was miscalculated, says Harold Camping" - What, *again*? Oh, wait, he just moved it to October this time. Hilarious! I love doomsday predictions. I wonder what he will say in October. :-)

Comment: I'd love to see a Xeno's Paradox of date predictions from the guy... each one shorter and shorter than the last.

Comment: @aslum - Ha ha.

Comment: @sklivvz : but did he even "profit" from the media coverage even from a non-financial point of view? I mean, I'm sure he has lost a lot of cred amongst his devotees

Comment: Nitpick: his 5/21 prediction wasn't the end of the world, it was the rapture (Christians taken to Heaven, world continues existing). Along with that, he predicted the actual end of the world in October. His post-5/21 revision is essentially "Rapture wasn't quite as expected, world still ending in October".

Comment: Let me add that the silly part of predicting the rapture for 5/21 is not the date part, it's the rapture part.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would seem not. Certainly not much.

Donations to Family Radio were huge over the last few years, but it does appear that the money was spent on advertizing the date of the Apocalyse, which was of course the point. [This article](http://www.mercurynews.com/top-stories/ci_18089431?nclick_check=1) talks quite a bit about the finances of Family Radio:

> In 2009, in the last Family Radio tax return that was made public, the group collected $18.4 million in contributions, and earned more than $1 million in investment and other income. That year the group spent $36.7 million, and $41.2 million the previous year.
>
> "Donations have picked up, but not enough to offset the amount of money we're spending," said [Family Radio board member Tom] Evans

In other words, Family Radio was spending more than it earned on the Apocalyse.

Camping says that he works on a voluntary basis for Family Radio. [Charity Navigator](http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.summary&orgid=3686), with which Family Radio has a 4 star rating, backs this up.

Comment: if that's true, kind of have to feel sorry for him. He's a good, but deranged man. Unless of course, he happened to own shares in the companies he chose to "advertise" with?